# Java how to insert a comma every 3 characters

Tags: java

Hello I have a programme that displays a different amount of money every time.
The money is displayed like this:

```
money: 2500000
```

I want it to looklike this:

```
money: 2,500,000
```

How can I change the string from the first example to the second example?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(your_number));
```

Answer (score 2):

The least code is:

```
new DecimalFormat(",###").format(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Format your number using locale US. Assuming money is an integer holding the amount

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(money)
```

This will return the amount formatted to the output you are asking.